# Phonegap - Android Geolocation is not accurate

Tags: android, cordova

I use cordova

```
// Platform: android
// 3.5.1
```

When I use Geolocation

```
var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(that.geoSuccess, that.geoError, options);
this.geoSuccess = function(position) {
            console.log("geoSuccess :"+position.coords.latitude+", "+ position.coords.longitude)
            that.mylocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        };
```

I get in the log:

```
31.4956033, 34.9326514
```

which is a 3.7 Kilometre from my actual location.

**Any idea why? or how to fix?**

on ios I get the following position:

```
31.518463052524, 34.90405467862522
```

which is my actual position, therefore the code is correct.

When I use google map (on the android device) my position is correct, therefore it's not hardware problem.

in my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this problem as well.  However, when I polled my location for change using watchPosition, it fixed it for me.  From what I can tell, the initial GPS fix is inaccurate.  Given time it closes the distance.

Something like:

```
 watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

 function onSuccess(position) {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    if(marker!=null)
       marker.setMap(null);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: myLatLng,
       map: map,
       title: 'My Location'
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for high accuracy

```
var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(that.geoSuccess, that.geoError, options);
```

[Geolocation options](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md#geolocationoptions)